# How to perform partial correlation with "correlation" package (without using "pcor" package)?

Tags: r, tidyverse, correlation

So as the title says, I'm looking for a way to run a partial correlation within R's "correlation" package, as I generally find it easier to work with most correlation stuff I've done in the past. However, per the CRAN pdf:

https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/correlation/correlation.pdf

I see that the argument for running a partial correlation is simply:

```
correlation(partial = T)
```

Thats fine, but I'm a bit confused as to how that works. For example, if I decide to do this in pcor, its fairly straight forward; you just plug x in (independent variable), y (dependent variable) and z (control variable) like so:

```
pcor.test(x = df$variable1,
      y = df$variable2,
      z = df$variable3)
```

But for the correlation package, it seems a bit unclear. Normally I've just run the correlation by default with Pearson or selected the method as Kendall's tau or Spearman's rho. However, in this case, the documentation as far as partial is not as clear. So if I was running a normal correlation with the starwars dataset, it would look like this:

```
starwars %>% 
  select(mass,
         height,
         birth_year) %>% 
  correlation()
```

Which gives me this default Pearson's r value:

```
Parameter1 | Parameter2 |     r |         95% CI |     t | df |       p
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
mass       |     height |  0.13 | [-0.13,  0.38] |  1.02 | 57 | 0.312  
mass       | birth_year |  0.48 | [ 0.18,  0.70] |  3.17 | 34 | 0.010**
height     | birth_year | -0.40 | [-0.63, -0.11] | -2.79 | 41 | 0.016*
```

If I add in this partial script:

```
starwars %>% 
  select(mass,
         height,
         birth_year) %>% 
  correlation(partial = T)
```

It now gives me this:

```
Parameter1 | Parameter2 |     r |         95% CI | t(34) |         p
--------------------------------------------------------------------
mass       |     height |  0.38 | [ 0.06,  0.63] |  2.38 | 0.023*   
mass       | birth_year |  0.58 | [ 0.30,  0.76] |  4.10 | < .001***
height     | birth_year | -0.53 | [-0.73, -0.24] | -3.60 | 0.002**
```

So I guess my two questions are 1) what variable here is being controlled if there is any actually being controlled and 2) if this isnt controlling correlation in any way, how do I modify the script to make it do this? I dont inherently have any problems with pcor, I would just greatly prefer being able to use as many functions in one library as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the solution. It was because I was using ppcor's "pcor.test" function and not "pcor" to compare with the correlation matrix from the correlation package's "correlation" function. I have shown how to run both below.

First, I used the following data:

```
    structure(list(Mins_Work = c(435L, 350L, 145L, 135L, 15L, 60L, 
60L, 390L, 395L, 395L, 315L, 80L, 580L, 175L, 545L, 230L, 435L, 
370L, 255L, 515L, 330L, 65L, 115L, 550L, 420L, 45L, 266L, 196L, 
198L, 220L, 17L, 382L, 0L, 180L, 343L, 207L, 263L, 332L, 259L, 
417L, 282L, 685L, 517L, 111L, 64L, 466L, 499L, 460L, 269L, 300L, 
427L, 301L, 436L, 342L, 229L, 379L, 102L, 94L, 345L, 73L, 204L, 
512L, 113L, 458L, 552L, 108L, 335L, 508L, 546L, 396L, 159L, 325L, 
747L, 650L, 461L, 669L, 186L, 220L, 410L, 708L, 409L, 515L, 413L, 
166L, 451L, 660L, 177L, 192L, 191L, 461L, 637L, 297L, 601L), 
    Mins_Sleep = c(300L, 540L, 540L, 480L, 480L, 480L, 480L, 
    420L, 300L, 240L, 480L, 300L, 420L, 360L, 390L, 405L, 420L, 
    360L, 420L, 350L, 420L, 450L, 445L, 480L, 300L, 400L, 310L, 
    390L, 350L, 450L, 390L, 390L, 510L, 452L, 310L, 360L, 500L, 
    360L, 420L, 420L, 420L, 382L, 430L, 393L, 240L, 400L, 480L, 
    450L, 450L, 359L, 420L, 361L, 360L, 480L, 570L, 340L, 450L, 
    180L, 510L, 420L, 425L, 407L, 360L, 510L, 360L, 368L, 410L, 
    360L, 510L, 436L, 291L, 420L, 240L, 300L, 420L, 420L, 424L, 
    520L, 240L, 390L, 480L, 300L, 480L, 390L, 300L, 360L, 420L, 
    360L, 480L, 330L, 375L, 390L, 458L), Coffee_Cups = c(3L, 
    0L, 2L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
    0L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 
    1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 8L, 3L, 5L, 0L, 2L, 
    2L, 8L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 
    5L, 0L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 3L, 0L, 5L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 
    3L, 3L, 1L, 9L, 9L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 0L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 
    3L, 9L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -93L))
```

Then I ran this dataset, which only has three variables, in the pcor function:

```
pcor(work_clean)
```

Which gives me these values. The first row is the correlation matrix of r values I was looking for originally:

```
$estimate
             Mins_Work Mins_Sleep Coffee_Cups
Mins_Work    1.0000000 -0.2520279   0.4448886
Mins_Sleep  -0.2520279  1.0000000   0.2803302
Coffee_Cups  0.4448886  0.2803302   1.0000000

$p.value
               Mins_Work  Mins_Sleep  Coffee_Cups
Mins_Work   0.000000e+00 0.015368604 8.863486e-06
Mins_Sleep  1.536860e-02 0.000000000 6.798296e-03
Coffee_Cups 8.863486e-06 0.006798296 0.000000e+00

$statistic
            Mins_Work Mins_Sleep Coffee_Cups
Mins_Work    0.000000  -2.470701    4.712651
Mins_Sleep  -2.470701   0.000000    2.770535
Coffee_Cups  4.712651   2.770535    0.000000

$n
[1] 93

$gp
[1] 1

$method
[1] "pearson"
```

After, I ran the pcor test:

```
pcor.test(x=work_clean$Mins_Work,
          y=work_clean$Mins_Sleep,
          z=work_clean$Coffee_Cups)
```

Which only gives me one sig value that matches the p value table above:

```
    estimate   p.value statistic  n gp  Method
1 -0.2520279 0.0153686 -2.470701 93  1 pearson
```

Then when I ran it in the correlation function:

```
work_clean %>% 
  correlation(partial = T)
```

It gave me this much nicer matrix that packages all of these values into one neat table:

```
# Correlation Matrix (pearson-method)

Parameter1 |  Parameter2 |     r |         95% CI | t(91) |         p
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Mins_Work  |  Mins_Sleep | -0.25 | [-0.43, -0.05] | -2.48 | 0.015*   
Mins_Work  | Coffee_Cups |  0.44 | [ 0.27,  0.59] |  4.74 | < .001***
Mins_Sleep | Coffee_Cups |  0.28 | [ 0.08,  0.46] |  2.79 | 0.013*   

p-value adjustment method: Holm (1979)
Observations: 93
```

As a comparison, if I just use the base correlation function:

```
work_clean %>% 
  correlation()
```

This is what the matrix looks like without controlling for the three variable relations with each other:

```
# Correlation Matrix (pearson-method)

Parameter1 |  Parameter2 |     r |        95% CI | t(91) |         p
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Mins_Work  |  Mins_Sleep | -0.15 | [-0.34, 0.06] | -1.43 | 0.157    
Mins_Work  | Coffee_Cups |  0.40 | [ 0.22, 0.56] |  4.20 | < .001***
Mins_Sleep | Coffee_Cups |  0.19 | [-0.01, 0.38] |  1.89 | 0.125    

p-value adjustment method: Holm (1979)
Observations: 93
```